# NullPointerException Android Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I know this question has been asked a lot and I am sorry for asking but I am completely lost and trying to learn this.

So i understand the general concept of the null pointer but I am having trouble with it on my SImpleCursorAdpater. I am trying to populate a listview in my fragment using the simple adapter but I am running into the problem

**Creating the adapter in the fragment**

```
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //opeing the DBApater
    db = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
    try {
        db.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //opening the Recipes_Adapter
    recipes = new Recipes_Adapter(getActivity());
    try {
        recipes.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Cursor cursor = recipes.getAllRecipes();

    String[] columns = new String[] {Recipes_Adapter.NAME};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.recipe_name};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row,cursor, columns,to, 0);

    ListView recipeList = (ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list);
    recipeList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter); //error is on this line

}
```

**R.layout.row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_name"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Recipe Layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D1FFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
        android:divider="#0000CC"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**LogCat**

```
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: app.rory.menu, PID: 10625
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.rory.menu/app.rory.pocket_chef.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at app.rory.pocket_chef.Fragments.recipes_Fragment.onActivityCreated(recipes_Fragment.java:63)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2061)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:912)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-13 20:13:48.914 10625-10625/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: the code looks ok, put your logcat and remove final keyword from ListView

Comment: where setting `Recipe Layout` layout for Fragment ?

Comment: Updated question to show the logs

Comment: `...setAdapter(..` on a null object reference means that `recipeList` is `null` in your code. That can only be `null` if `(ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.recipe_list);` returned null. And that's typically the case when you're using the wrong layout id. It has to exist inside the layout that is referenced as `rootview`.

Comment: `recipeList` is null for you. Looks like you are using the right view id for the `ListView`. Check if you are inflating `RecipeLayout.xml` for the fragment in the `onCreateView` ?

Comment: Thanks guys its solved now, I wasnt inflating the correct layout in the onCreate!

Answer (score 0):

move all code written inside onActivityCreated() method to onViewCreated() method, It will work.
basically onActivityCreated doesn't guarantee that your xml has been inflated and all views are present in view hierarchy but onViewCreated() does.